# Ruby: map an array of keys to values shorthand

Tags: ruby, hash, dictionary, proc, collect

I just started with Ruby recently and I'm hoping there is a shorthand for using a bound method as a proc I'm missing.  I'm trying to do this essentially

```
SYMBOLS = {"I" => 1, "V" => 5, "X" => 10, ... }

roman = "zXXIV".upcase.chars.collect { |c| SYMBOLS[c] }
=> [nil, 10, 10, 1, 5]
```

I feel like there should be an easy way in ruby to just use SYMBOLS[] as a bound method, so just

```
roman = str.upcase.chars.collect &:SYMBOLS[]
```

**Solution Ruby 1.9.3**

roman = SYMBOLS.values_at(*str.upcase.chars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SYMBOLS.values_at(str.upcase.chars.to_a)
```

Regarding using `SYMBOLS[]`, you'd still need to pass the character to the method.

You can *get* the method via `SYMBOLS.method(:[])`, e.g.,

```
> p = SYMBOLS.method(:[])
> p.call("X")
=> 10
```

I'm not convinced it's the most readable in this case–for me, calling `map` and passing in `SYMBOLS[]`, while concise and functional, delays understanding what's happening longer than I prefer.

Comment: Great, is there a more general way?

Comment: @agoebel What's not general about `Hash.values_at`?

Comment: Guess I need to get a better feel for the ruby object model still. I was just wondering for the general solution if I had a custom class/method I wanted to do the same thing with.

Comment: @agoebel Then using `map` as Phrogz suggested is what you should accept as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SYMBOLS = {"I" => 1, "V" => 5, "X" => 10 }
roman = "zXXIV"

p roman.chars.map(&SYMBOLS.method(:[]))
#=> [nil, 10, 10, 1, 5]
```

Comment: +1, IMO this is better, maybe. I'm undecided. I actually think `values_at` is a bit more communicative, I guess. But my objection is communication, not technical.